# Values not appearing after join in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, csv, attribute-joins

After joining a CSV file, the columns in the attribute table show up as if the shapefile and CSV are joined, but no data shows up. After playing around with it, I found that if I join a second CSV file that has identical names for the provinces, I can get the values of the original to show up (if you're interested, joining the second CSV file alone will display its values).

Since I can access my data in the end, it's not an urgent question, but I was interested in what's going on. Here are some screenshots of what is being displayed.

Shapefile attributes table showing no values after being joined to CSV 1:
[image: Shapefile attributes table showing no values after being joined to CSV 1]
Shapefile attributes table showing values of CSV 1 after being joined to CSV 1 and CSV 2:
[image: Shapefile attributes table showing values of CSV 1 after being joined to CSV 1 and CSV 2]

Edit: Though I was originally able to see the data when I joined both CSV files, ArcMap would not show the values when choosing the symbology. I was able get things to display by creating a new CSV with the data from both and by changing the title of the Total Outputs from "TOut####" to "TO####". Still unsure of why there was ever a problem, though.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please [edit] your question to include the actual screenshots (using the Image button on the edit toolbar) rather than a link to images off-site.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSV filenames contain non-alpha numeric characters e.g. ( and ,

Try renaming your CSV and do the join again.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I'm certain the problem had nothing to do with the file name. The new file that had both sets of information was named "All Data (arcgis)", and that one didn't work when the columns was labeled "TOut####" but did work when the columns were renamed to "TO####". My only thought was that it didn't like the lower case letters, but it accepted the "Provinces" column just fine...

Comment: Yeah, perhaps it does not like case mixing when there are also numbers in the field name. Another thing to try is to export the .CSV to .DBF before doing the join, which tends to clean up various quirks like this.